# Does this the limit exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Assume that there exist constants $c_i>0, i=1,\dots,5$, $\beta>1\ge\gamma>0$, and $
    \theta>0$ such that
  \begin{eqnarray}
   & &c_1 |x|^\beta\le V(x)\le c_2 |x|^\beta,\qquad c_4r^\theta\le \mu(B(x,r))\le c_5r^\theta,\\
   && \frac{|V(x)-V(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}\le c_3\big(\max\{ |x|,|y|\}\big)^{\beta-\gamma}
  \end{eqnarray}
  for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and sufficently large $r>0$.

Let $ V^\wedge $ (resp. $V^\vee $) be the piecewise constant function which takes the value $\sup_{x\in X_i} V(x)$ (resp. $\inf_{x\in X_i} V(x)$) on $X_i=[i,i+1]$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I want to know that whether the limit
$$\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\frac{\mu(\{x\in \mathbb{R}:V^\vee(x)\le \lambda\})}{\mu(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:V^\wedge(x)\le \lambda\})}$$
 exists or not?

It is easy to check that
$$ \lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\frac{\mu(\{x\in \mathbb{R}:V^\vee(x)\le \lambda\})}{\mu(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:V^\wedge(x)\le \lambda\})}\ge 1.$$ Moreover, I have showed the folowing staements:

For any $i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and any $x,y\in X_i$,
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:Bohr_01}
  \begin{aligned}
    |V(x)-V(y)|&\le c_3|x-y|^\gamma\big(\max\{ |x|,|y|\}\big)^{\beta-\gamma}\\
    &\le c_3|X_i|^\gamma\big(\max\{ |x|,|y|\}\big)^{\beta-\gamma}
     \\
    &=c_3\big(\max\{ |x|,|y|\}\big)^{\beta-\gamma}.
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
  By the definition of $V^b(x)$, $b\in \{\vee,\wedge\}$, there exist two sequences $\{x_{n,m}\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq X_i$, $m=1,2$, such that $V^\wedge(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}V(x_{n,1})$ and $V^\vee(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}V(x_{n,2})$ for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in X_i$. It follows that, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|\ge 1$,
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:V_-+}
    \begin{aligned}
      V^\wedge(x)-V^\vee(x)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}(V(x_{n,1})-V(x_{n,2}))\\
      &\le c_4\big(\lim_{n\to \infty}\max\{ |x_{n,1}|,|x_{n,2}|\}\big)^{\beta-\gamma}\\
      &\le c_4\big(  |x|+ 1\big)^{\beta-\gamma}\le c_5|x|^{\beta-\gamma}.
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

Thanks very much for you help.